# XSLT - Can't get data from node, when using xml:when

Tags: xslt

I have a problem getting data from a node, when I'm using `xml:choose` and `xml:when`. I only get the result `NaN` or the value from the main xml-file, even if.

Part of the XML-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Job xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
  <Invoice>
    <InvoiceLine>
      <LineNo>1</LineNo>
      <QtyInSecondUnit>56</QtyInSecondUnit>
      <Quantity>56</Quantity>
      <CustTaric>
        <StatNo>34011100</StatNo>
        <IssuingCountry>GB</IssuingCountry>
      </CustTaric>
    </InvoiceLine>
    <InvoiceLine>
      <LineNo>2</LineNo>
      <QtyInSecondUnit>22</QtyInSecondUnit>
      <Quantity>0</Quantity>
      <CustTaric>
        <StatNo>44152020</StatNo>
        <IssuingCountry>GB</IssuingCountry>
      </CustTaric>
    </InvoiceLine>
  </Invoice>
</Job>
```

Part of the XSLT-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

      <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Job/Invoice"/>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="Job/Invoice/InvoiceLine">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="QtyInSecondUnit"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Quantity"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="CustTaric/StatNo"/>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="QtyInSecondUnit">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="/Job/Invoice/InvoiceLine/CustTaric/StatNo = '44152020'">
            <xsl:value-of select="number(translate(Job/Invoice/InvoiceLine/NetMass,',','.')) div 25"/>
          </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>   
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="Quantity">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="/Job/Invoice/InvoiceLine/CustTaric/StatNo = '44152020'">
            <xsl:value-of select="'0'"/>
          </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="CustTaric/StatNo">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:template>
```

Hope there is somebody how can tell me (the noob) what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the line producing `NaN`

```
<xsl:value-of select="number(translate(Job/Invoice/InvoiceLine/NetMass,',','.')) div 25"/>
```

There are two problems (one of which is probably where you have over-simplified your XML)

1. The xpath expression you are using will be relative to the current node you are positioned on. There is no `Job` element under the current `QtyInSecondUnit` element
2. There is no `NetMass` element in your XML in your question

Assuming `NetMass` does exist in your actual XML, and is a child of the parent `InvoiceLine` the expression you want is this

```
<xsl:value-of select="number(translate(../NetMass,',','.')) div 25"/>
```

There is also an issue with your `xsl:when` (possibly)

```
 <xsl:when test="/Job/Invoice/InvoiceLine/CustTaric/StatNo = '44152020'">
```

This will test for any `CustTaric/StatNo` anywhere in the document. Perhaps you only want to test for the one in the current `InvoiceLine`? If so, do this...

```
<xsl:when test="../CustTaric/StatNo = '44152020'">
```

Note, you could rewrite your XSLT to put the logic in template matches, rather than `xsl:choose`

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="Job/Invoice/InvoiceLine">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="QtyInSecondUnit"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Quantity"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="CustTaric/StatNo"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="InvoiceLine[CustTaric/StatNo = '44152020']/QtyInSecondUnit">
    <xsl:value-of select="number(translate(../NetMass,',','.')) div 25"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="QtyInSecondUnit">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="InvoiceLine[CustTaric/StatNo = '44152020']/Quantity">
    <xsl:value-of select="'0'"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Quantity">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CustTaric/StatNo">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Strictly speaking, the templates that just do `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` can be removed, as XSLT's built-in templates will do exactly the same thing if there is no matching template in the XSLT.

Comment: Thank you :) Works brilliantly!

Comment: @ Tim C The noob is stuck again...heh (ashamed). I just wish to sum up Quantity, in all lines where StatNo is not 44152020.

Comment: The expression is probably `sum(Job/Invoice/InvoiceLine[CustTaric/StatNo != '44152020']/Quantity)`, but if you can't get it to work, feel free to ask a whole new question. Thanks!